# Fail to register embedded Derby driver into WildFly 25

Tags: java, wildfly, derby

I have a task from my teacher to make Wildfly+embedded Debry server, but on windows, Wildfly just refusing to register the embedded driver.

I have derby jars and module.xml inside WildFly modules folder. But when im trying to register them as modules via Jboss-cli.bat, with commands:

```
`/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=derby-embedded:add(driver-name=derby-embedded, \
 driver-module-name=org.apache.derby, \
 driver-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver, \
 driver-datasource-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource, \
 driver-xa-datasource-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource)`
```

All what i getting in server log is:

```
 21:14:49,310 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/shared/common/security/SystemPermission
    
    21:14:49,311 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(JDBCBoot.java:93)
    
    21:14:49,311 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(JDBCBoot.java:68)
    
    21:14:49,311 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(EmbeddedDriver.java:95)
    
    21:14:49,311 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    
    21:14:49,311 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    
    21:14:49,311 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    
    21:14:49,311 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    
    21:14:49,311 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    
    21:14:49,311 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.connector@25.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.performRuntime(JdbcDriverAdd.java:165)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler.performRuntime(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:343)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:164)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1045)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:777)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:466)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1427)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:448)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$executeForResponse$0(ModelControllerImpl.java:259)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:304)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:270)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.executeForResponse(ModelControllerImpl.java:259)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.executeOperation(ModelControllerImpl.java:253)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:236)
    
    21:14:49,312 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:241)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$400(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:139)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:163)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:159)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:328)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:285)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.execute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:159)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.protocol@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$1.doExecute(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:70)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.protocol@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$AsyncTaskRunner.run(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:160)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    
    21:14:49,313 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    
    21:14:49,314 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    
    21:14:49,314 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
    
    21:14:49,314 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.shared.common.security.SystemPermission from [Module "org.apache.derby" from local module loader @428640fa (finder: local module finder @d9345cd (roots: F:\etc\wildfly-25.0.1.Final\modules,F:\etc\wildfly-25.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    
    21:14:49,314 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    
    21:14:49,314 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    
    21:14:49,314 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    
    21:14:49,314 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    
    21:14:49,314 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     ... 39 more
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/shared/common/security/SystemPermission
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(JDBCBoot.java:93)
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(JDBCBoot.java:68)
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<init>(EmbeddedDriver.java:102)
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.connector@25.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.performRuntime(JdbcDriverAdd.java:165)
    
    21:14:49,315 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler.performRuntime(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:343)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:164)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1045)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:777)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:466)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1427)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:448)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$executeForResponse$0(ModelControllerImpl.java:259)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:304)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:270)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.executeForResponse(ModelControllerImpl.java:259)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.executeOperation(ModelControllerImpl.java:253)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:236)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:241)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$400(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:139)
    
    21:14:49,316 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:163)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:159)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:328)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:285)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.execute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:159)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.protocol@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$1.doExecute(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:70)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.protocol@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$AsyncTaskRunner.run(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:160)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
    
    21:14:49,317 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.shared.common.security.SystemPermission from [Module "org.apache.derby" from local module loader @428640fa (finder: local module finder @d9345cd (roots: F:\etc\wildfly-25.0.1.Final\modules,F:\etc\wildfly-25.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    
    21:14:49,318 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    
    21:14:49,318 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    
    21:14:49,318 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    
    21:14:49,318 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    
    21:14:49,318 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     ... 39 more
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/shared/common/security/SystemPermission
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(JDBCBoot.java:93)
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(JDBCBoot.java:68)
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.getDriverModule(AutoloadedDriver.java:217)
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.getDriverModule(EmbeddedDriver.java:184)
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.apache.derby//org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.getMajorVersion(EmbeddedDriver.java:145)
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.connector@25.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.startDriverServices(JdbcDriverAdd.java:179)
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.connector@25.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.performRuntime(JdbcDriverAdd.java:169)
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler.performRuntime(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:343)
    
    21:14:49,319 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:164)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1045)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:777)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:466)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1427)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:448)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$executeForResponse$0(ModelControllerImpl.java:259)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:304)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:270)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.executeForResponse(ModelControllerImpl.java:259)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.executeOperation(ModelControllerImpl.java:253)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:236)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:241)
    
    21:14:49,320 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$400(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:139)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:163)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:159)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:328)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:285)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.controller@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.execute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:159)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.protocol@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$1.doExecute(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:70)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.as.protocol@17.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContextImpl$AsyncTaskRunner.run(ManagementRequestContextImpl.java:160)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    
    21:14:49,321 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    
    21:14:49,322 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    
    21:14:49,322 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    
    21:14:49,322 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
    
    21:14:49,322 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.shared.common.security.SystemPermission from [Module "org.apache.derby" from local module loader @428640fa (finder: local module finder @d9345cd (roots: F:\etc\wildfly-25.0.1.Final\modules,F:\etc\wildfly-25.0.1.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    
    21:14:49,322 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    
    21:14:49,322 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    
    21:14:49,322 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    
    21:14:49,322 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    
    21:14:49,322 ERROR [stderr] (management-handler-thread - 1)     ... 37 more
    
    21:14:49,323 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYJCA0003: Unable to instantiate driver class "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver": java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Driver.getMajorVersion()" because the return value of "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.getDriverModule()" is null
    21:14:49,324 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("jdbc-driver" => "derby-embedded")
    ]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0034: Unable to instantiate driver class \"org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver\". See log (WARN) for more details"
```

What can cause this problem? Derby version is 10.15.2.0, WildFly wildfly-25.0.1.Final.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It turned out all i needed to do is to add derbyclient.jar into CLASSPATH in windows 7. And copy via what ever method derbyclient.jar to Wildfly modules folder.